# Python Multiprocessing Logging Error - TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, multiprocessing

I've got a python3 (3.4.5) project I've been working on that utilizes `multiprocessing.Pool` to run around 50+ jobs through 4 workers.  I have a separate process setup with a `logging.handlers.QueueListener` so I can log global stuff to a single file via a `Queue` used with `multiprocessing.Manager()`.  So basically the flow goes like this

1. Main program Starts
2. Create `Queue` via `multiprocessing.Manager()`
3. Start dedicated logging process with a `QueueListener` listening to the `Queue` I just created for the global log. (I've also tried this just using a thread off of the main program with the same results.)
4. Create a `multiprocessing.Pool` to process the individual jobs, passing them the `Queue` created previously and the necessary config info to run and setup their logging (there's a global log, plus an individual log for each job with more granular info). The jobs are started with `map_async`.
5. Wait for all of the jobs to process, then do some final steps and clean-up.

I keep getting an intermittent error on some of the jobs though, usually there is an error on 1 of the jobs (a different one each time), occasionally there are 2 of the same errors or zero though. As far as I can tell, it's not the code in the jobs that's causing the error, but something in either the `multiprocessing` or `logging` setup.  Here's an example of the error I'm getting:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/handlers.py", line 1347, in emit
    self.enqueue(self.prepare(record))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/handlers.py", line 1313, in enqueue
    self.queue.put_nowait(record)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put_nowait
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 731, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 413, in _send_bytes
    self._send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 369, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
Call stack:
  File "./sampling__test__py.py", line 100, in <module>
    run_pool     = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 118, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 168, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 233, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 267, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 21, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 77, in _launch
    code = process_obj._bootstrap()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/home/username/value_check.py", line 338, in value_check
    global_logger.info("SplitTime: {str_timeDelta} -- COMPLETED: {Check_Name} --- Total Txn Count: {var_Total_Txn_Count} --- Criteria Txn Count: {var_Criteria_Txn_Count} --- Threshold: {Threshold} --- Low_Vol Threshold: {LowVolThresh}".format(str_timeDelta = timeDelta(datetime.now() - YAML_Config['start_time']), **YAML_Config))
Message: 'SplitTime: 00:01:05,031 -- COMPLETED: ALPHA_CHECK --- Total Txn Count: 1234--- Criteria Txn Count: 0 --- Threshold: 10 --- Low_Vol Threshold: 0'
Arguments: None
```

The error in the code refers back to a logging object in my code, but even when I put `try/except` logic around the call it doesn't do anything, the error appears to be happening upstream.  I've also tried changing what is being logged from a formatted string to just a simple string to no avail.  It seems like somewhere along the way the individual jobs are either losing their connection to the `Queue` or something in the `Queue` is failing and causing the problems.

Any ideas?  I've been working to get a newer version of Python available which would be beneficial for a number of reasons (f-strings in particular), but I don't know if that'd resolve this issue and I'm running out of troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, it's that code that's failing, not the actual logging call from my code.  Any thoughts on why that exception is happening in the first place though?

Answer (score 3):

> Even when I put try/except logic around the call it doesn't do anything.

That's likely because, if the logging package encounters an exception that has to do with logging itself, it will print the traceback, but not raise the exception itself.  This is more fully explained in the docstring for [`logging.Handler.handleError`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.handleError).

One place to start is by setting:

```
logging.raiseExceptions = True
```

> If the module-level attribute raiseExceptions is False, exceptions get silently ignored.

If that doesn't help, you could put an `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` call in the code for [`.emit()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1a2b52bbd2c6513aaf5bb915890ea7647713d5df/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L974); something like:

```
def emit(self, record):
    try:
        msg = self.format(record)
        stream = self.stream
        stream.write(msg)
        stream.write(self.terminator)
        self.flush()
    except Exception as e:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  # < ---
        self.handleError(record)
```

Where `record` will be a `LogRecord` instance.  Usually when I see a logging error pop up, it's because I've used the wrong number of args for the given format string, but inspect that `record` object should hopefully tell you more.

Lastly there is, from the call stack, your logging call itself:

```
global_logger.info(
    "SplitTime: {str_timeDelta} -- "
    "COMPLETED: {Check_Name} --- "
    "Total Txn Count: {var_Total_Txn_Count} --- "
    "Criteria Txn Count: {var_Criteria_Txn_Count} --- "
    "Threshold: {Threshold} --- "
    "Low_Vol Threshold: {LowVolThresh}".format(
    str_timeDelta = timeDelta(datetime.now() - YAML_Config['start_time']), **YAML_Config))
```

Tough to say exactly what is ultimately raise the exception since the string does appear to be fully formatted.  (Though we can't see `YAML_Config`.)

Regardless of that, one recommendation: you can take advantage of using logging's "lazy" string formatting rather than `str.format()` as you currently have.  The `str.format()` call will get evaluated as soon as it can, whereas if you pass kwargs to `global_logger.info()`, the logging package will wait to evaluate them until it must.

Comment: Great feedback.  I've been playing around with this and overrode the `QueueHandler`, but it everything looks good there as far as I can tell.  It seems to me something fishy is going on with the `multiprocessing.Manager` somehow.

Comment: I am not sure, but this might be related. Haven't gone through it in detail. https://codewithoutrules.com/2018/09/04/python-multiprocessing/

Answer (score 1):

I have just encountered similar issue with python3.10. I'm writing log messages to multiprocessing Queue and randomly was getting this:

```
    self.queue.put(obj)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 817, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

It looks for me as some kind of race condition and have fixed it with lock:

```
with self.lock:
    self.queue.put(msg)
```

Both lock and queue were created with manager:

```
self.pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
self.manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
self.queue = self.manager.Queue(-1)
self.lock = self.manager.Lock()
```